# When the coordinates of my snake are the same as my random item, the console is supposed to print "You got the item!" but it doesn't. Why?

Tags: python, function, object, pygame, coordinates

Here is the code to create the bases of my Snake.

```
class Snake(object):
    x_coordinate = 0
    y_coordinate = 0

    def __init__(self, x_coordinate, y_coordinate):
        grid[x_coordinate][y_coordinate] = 1
        Snake.x_coordinate = x_coordinate
        Snake.y_coordinate = y_coordinate
        print(Snake.x_coordinate)
        print(Snake.y_coordinate)

    @staticmethod
    def move_snake(direction):
        if direction == "UP":
            old_x = Snake.x_coordinate
            old_y = Snake.y_coordinate
            grid[old_x][old_y] = 0
            grid[old_x - 1][old_y] = 1
            Snake.x_coordinate = old_x - 1
            print("UP")
        if direction == "DOWN":
            old_x = Snake.x_coordinate
            old_y = Snake.y_coordinate
            grid[old_x][old_y] = 0
            grid[old_x + 1][old_y] = 1
            Snake.x_coordinate = old_x + 1
            print("DOWN")
        if direction == "LEFT":
            old_x = Snake.x_coordinate
            old_y = Snake.y_coordinate
            grid[old_x][old_y] = 0
            grid[old_x][old_y - 1] = 1
            Snake.y_coordinate = old_y - 1
            print("LEFT")
        if direction == "RIGHT":
            old_x = Snake.x_coordinate
            old_y = Snake.y_coordinate
            grid[old_x][old_y] = 0
            grid[old_x][old_y + 1] = 1
            Snake.y_coordinate = old_y + 1
            print("RIGHT")
        print("Your X and Y coordinates are {0} and {1}".format(Snake.x_coordinate, Snake.y_coordinate))
```

Here is the code to create my Random Object that needs to be obtained.

```
class RandomObject(object):
    x_coordinate = 0
    y_coordinate = 0

    def __init__(self):
        x_coordinate = random.randint(1, 15)
        y_coordinate = random.randint(1, 15)
        grid[x_coordinate][y_coordinate] = 2
        print("The items x and y coordinates are {0} and {1}".format(x_coordinate, y_coordinate))
```

I declared them both as snake and random_item variables. I put this in my pygame events function too.

```
    elif snake.x_coordinate == randomItem.x_coordinate and snake.y_coordinate == randomItem.y_coordinate:
        print("You got the item.")
```

So what is the issue here? it should work because when I move the snake to the random item coordinate it prints that they are at the same coordinate but nothing happens, the event is not triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never set instance attributes:

```
class RandomObject(object):
    x_coordinate = 0
    y_coordinate = 0

    def __init__(self):
        x_coordinate = random.randint(1, 15)
        y_coordinate = random.randint(1, 15)
        grid[x_coordinate][y_coordinate] = 2
        print("The items x and y coordinates are {0} and {1}".format(x_coordinate, y_coordinate))
```

The `__init__` method sets *local values*, which are lost again when the function exits. The `RandomObject` instance has no attributes set, and so only the class attributes (both set to `0`) are ever found when you access the attributes on `randomItem`.

Set them *on the instance*:

```
class RandomObject(object):
    x_coordinate = 0
    y_coordinate = 0

    def __init__(self):
        self.x_coordinate = random.randint(1, 15)
        self.y_coordinate = random.randint(1, 15)
        grid[self.x_coordinate][self.y_coordinate] = 2
        print("The items x and y coordinates are {0} and {1}".format(self.x_coordinate, self.y_coordinate))
```

Note the `self.` references.